# Isotope with fluid grid and different element sizes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-isotope, fluid-layout

I am trying to create a site using isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co) and a fluid layout grid (http://unsemantic.com/) for the content of the site. I want it to be exactly like this: http://www.aarontolley.co.uk/

Only thing that should be different from the aarontolley site and the site I'm creating is that the elements will have different heights and widths.

What I have now is the following (for testing, hence the inline styling):

```
<div id="container" class="grid-container">
    <div class="element grid-33" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div style="height:150px; background-color:red;">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element grid-33" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div style="height:150px; background-color:red;">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element grid-33" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div style="height:150px; background-color:red;">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element grid-66" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div style="height:300px; background-color:red;">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element grid-33" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div style="height:150px; background-color:red;">test</div>
     </div>
 </div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#container').isotope();
    });
</script>
```

Without isotope, the markup looks like this:

[image: Markup without isotope]

And with isotope enabled, it looks like this:

[image: Markup with isotope]

Is this possible at all? :-)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this by using the grid from http://responsivegridsystem.com/ and then switched from isotope to http://masonry.desandro.com/ using the following settings:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 1,
            isAnimated: true,
            itemSelector: '.element'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Somehow the `columnWidth: 1` did the trick ;-)

Only downside of this is that I had to downgrade jQuery from the latest version to 1.8.3 :-) But I can sure live with that.

Screenr of the working grid: http://www.screenr.com/zWV7